# Default Constructors all encapsulated in the header files

Tags: c++, constructor

While in my class today, we had an exercise in inheritance. We were to write a UnderGrad class that inherited from a Student class which inherited from a Person class.

The Person had 3 variables to the class a name, an address and a birthday.

The Student had an ID number, Major and degree type.

And finally the Undergrad had a previous high school and credits earned variables.

When I wrote the header file for each of the classes, the default constructor looked something like this:

```
   //snippet from UnderGrad.h
 Undergrad(string nm = "", string add = "", string bday = "", int id = 0, string maj = "", string degtyp = "", string hs = "", int cred = 0) : Student(nm,add,bday,id,maj,degtyp) {

     highSchool = hs;
     credits = cred;
};


//snippet from Student.h
Student(string nm = "", string add = "", string bday = "", int id = 0, string maj = "", string degtyp = "") : Person(nm,add,bday){
     stuId = id;
     major = maj;
     degreeType = degtyp;
};

//snippet from Person.h
Person(string nm = "", string add = "", string bday = ""){
     name = nm;
     address = add;
     bDay = bday;
};
```

My professor said that this is unreadable and that its not really done this way.

I was wondering, what is wrong with creating default constructors this way? Is there anything wrong? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You should ask your professor which part of this they have a problem with.

Comment: The code is total clear! I think there's nothing to complain about.

Comment: The only thing that is unclear in this code is the rationale for using nested inheritance, and for having non-abstract, non-leaf classes. It seems very unlikely that this could be helpful in solving any actual programming problem.

Comment: A leaf class is a class which is at the bottom of the inheritance tree. That is, a class which no other class inherits from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the benefit of the context of the code, there are only a few things that I would change about these constructors.

1. I would consider moving the definitions of the constructors into separate source files. This will allow the definitions to be changed without triggering a recompile of the rest of your code. For small programs, or very simple constructors that are unlikely to change without the header also changing, this is probably not worth the effort.
2. I would change the definitions of the constructors to use the member initialiser list instead of assigning members in the constructor body. (See the answer from Als for an explanation).
3. I would remove the semicolons at the ends of the function definitions, they are totally unneeded.
4. I would split the long constructors into several lines, to avoid overly long lines of code (long lines may not fit in your editor, and could be hard to perform diffs and merges on).
5. It appears that you have a `using namespace ::std` or a `using ::std::string` somewhere in your header file. This is bad practice, because it means that code which includes your headers will have this `using` applied. This could make the meaning of the client code change, or make the client code become ambiguous and fail to compile. I would remove the `using`, and instead use a qualified name for `std::string`.

---

These changes put into action:

```
//snippet from UnderGrad.h
Undergrad(
    std::string nm = "",
    std::string add = "",
    std::string bday = "",
    int id = 0,
    std::string maj = "",
    std::string degtyp = "",
    std::string hs = "",
    int cred = 0) :
        Student(nm,add,bday,id,maj,degtyp),
        highSchool(hs),
        credits(cred)
{
}

//snippet from Student.h
Student(
    std::string nm = "",
    std::string add = "",
    std::string bday = "",
    int id = 0,
    std::string maj = "",
    std::string degtyp = "") :
      Person(nm,add,bday),
      stuId(id),
      major(maj),
      degreeType(degtyp)
{
}

//snippet from Person.h
Person(std::string nm = "", std::string add = "", std::string bday = "") :
    name(nm), address(add), bDay(bday)
{
}
```

Comment: Apt to mention here, except #2, the other points might be as per a persons choice or style, but not following #2 would really hurt the performance, and it should always be followed.

Comment: I don't know if it would *really* hurt performance - there would be a few more instructions executed per construction, but those instructions would likely pale in comparison to the buffer allocation inside the `string`'s constructor, so I doubt it would be noticeable.

Comment: #1 is probably harmless for small projects. #2 will probably not be a bottleneck, but it is necessary for copyable but non-assignable types. #3 is totally harmless (although the semicolons might not be legal?). #4 is a matter of personal style, and really depends on your development environment. #5 is poor style, but it is easy to fix if it ever actually causes a problem. Basically these are all nit-picks, but they may be helpful in any case.

Comment: The bigger issues with this code are the use of strings for everything (depending on how the code is intended to be used), and the unnecessary use of inheritance. It may be better to use a Date class for bDay (for example), but it really does depend on the intended use. The only really bad part of this code is probably the nested inheritance and non-abstract non-leaf classes, but again, this is impossible to comment on without having more code than was provided in the question.

Comment: We're eventually going to use a struct for most things like the dates, address and birthday. The point of this whole thing was just to illustrate inheritance. The program won't do anything practical. Right now, the only thing the program does is print out what all the variables are.

Answer (score -1):

Semantically fine, though you could possibly use initialisers for the member strings instead of assigning each one.

Stylistically, your lines are a little long, but that's about all I could take serious issue with.